# Angular js timeout for image slider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, slider, timeout

hello i am trying to make my Angular js images slider work from slide to slide to be as a slide show i did code the part for next and prev image but when i tried to code it to work auto it doesn't work.
  i really dont know why?.

i used : $timeout
 and i set a var with a time and then i put the next part of code in a function and  i called it but it doesn't work like that :

```
function nextSlide(){
         $scope.direction = 'right';
            $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex > 0) ? --$scope.currentIndex : $scope.slides.length - 1;
        $timeout($scope.nextSlide);
    }
```

and then i called it in my controller like that :

```
   var TimeToSlide = 3000;
 $timeout(nextSlide, TimeToSlide);
```

and i put time when it work every 3 seconds

and up in my controller i used the service

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) { // here i put my code }
```

here is my fiddle if anybody can guide me what to do .

http://jsfiddle.net/heshamelmasry/HB7LU/22863/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle you didn't include $timeout in your controller. And the $timeout was only in the nextSlide function. The buttons seem to be mixed up. Right button is previous and left is next. Because the code itself seems to be working after I fixed these issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/b15nrbpk/

```
$scope.prevSlide = function () {
    $scope.direction = 'left';
        $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex < $scope.slides.length - 1) ? ++$scope.currentIndex : 0;
        $timeout($scope.prevSlide, 3000);
    };


$scope.nextSlide = function () {
        $scope.direction = 'right';
        $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex > 0) ? --$scope.currentIndex : $scope.slides.length - 1;
        $timeout($scope.nextSlide, 3000);
    };
```

**Update**

You can simply call

```
 //Start the slideshow
 $scope.nextSlide();
```

In your controller. But the call has to be in the controller. See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmz9t9mL/)

Comment: thank you so much for you effort yes it works now but when i click on the next button bec yes i just run it when i click next BUT i want it to run on the load of the window when i load not when i click on next so i edit on your code and i created a function called loadSlides outside the controller and i called it on the controller but i doesn't work also http://jsfiddle.net/heshamelmasry/b15nrbpk/1/

Comment: Just call **$scope.nextSlide();** or **$scope.prevSlide();** onload. Then It should be work without click.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It seems you have to call the function after they are declared, otherwise it doesn't find them. Which you will see in the fiddle I created.

Comment: really thank you i really appreciate. it working fine now